# XSLT. Integration on php site

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I'd like to know how to integrate xslt into php site. I have one idea though...

PHP script serialize data and echo it

```
<?php 
echo '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<test>TEST</test>
';
?>
```

The XML output gets transformed by text.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output 
    method="html" 
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" 
    indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<h1>
<xsl:value-of select="test" />
</h1>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works perfectly well, but I am not sure that this is a good aproach. I'll be happy to get some tips.

**UPD#1** Robert suggested to use PHP extension. And here's what I got now:

```
<?php
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<test>TEST</test>';

$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load("test.xsl");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc); 
?>
```

As you see there's external xsl file and php that creates xml, loads both, xml and external xsl, to DOM and then passes it XSLTProcessor. This fits my needs. But would this be a "good practice"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the XML, you might want to look at one of the XSLT extensions for PHP, that way you're client is avoiding multiple round trips, plus with the method you're using you can't pass in parameters to the XSLT.

You can also use Javascript to run the XSLT on the client-side in a manner that allows passing in parameters, but due to browser compatibility issues. Client-side also means that the user is downloading both the XML and XSLT content, I would avoid that unless you are very concerned about server through-put as in my ad-hoc experience its generally much better to rely on the server-side environment which you can control.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have made an update. Is this what you meant?